# How to stay on same wizard on refreshing the page in Jquery-Steps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I am using jQuery-Steps plugin for my wizard type form. Now I want to stay on same wizard when I refresh the page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set  `saveState: true` in the options when you initialise `jQuery.steps`.

eg:

```
$("#example-basic").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    autoFocus: true,
    saveState: true
});
```

The saveState option is dependent on jQuery.cookie plugin. Ref: https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/issues/86

It's also important to not that saveState will not work on the local file system, it has to be served from a webserver due to browser restrictions.

---

**Resetting the state:**

In order to reset state when the wizard is completed you have to use jQuery to click the first step link. You can then hide the wizard and show a custom message so the user is not confused.

```
$("#example-basic").steps({
    ...
    onFinished: function( a ) {
        $('#example-basic .steps a:eq(0)').click();
        $('#example-basic').hide();
        $('#custom-message').show();
    }
});
```

This is the only way I've found to reset the state without altering or extending the plugin code.

Comment: This worked but it is saving state even after submitting the form. After submitting when I try to again edit the form it takes me to the last wizard(step) directly. How do I clear state on form submit?

Comment: I've updated the answer for how to reset the state. Unfortunately the steps plugin doesn't provide an easy way of modifying the state information.

Comment: This works but after submitting the form first wizard appears again for a second and then it goes to home page(where I'm redirecting after form submission). This will make confusion. Isn't there any other way to reset the state?

Comment: The cookie key is set in the plugin, you could technically just clear the cookie by hard-coding this key, but it might then break when you update the plugin. Use the following code at your own riks. You can in the onFinished function clear the cookie with the following code: `$.cookie('jQu3ry_5teps_St@te_' + $( this ).data( "uid" ), '' );`

Comment: Yes, that works fine! Why did you say "Use the following code at your own riks"? Are there any possible conflicts? (I'm not going to update the plugin)

Comment: There will be no conflicts as long as you do not update. "At your own risk" implies that the code is not future proof and will most likely break at some point after an update.

Comment: You mean it's a dirty hack!! I get that.

Comment: I am assigning multiple forms to a single user and I have set saveState: true. Now State of one form reflects in other form. For example if I am in wizard 4 in one form, it automatically redirects me to wizard 4 in other forms too because of cookies. Is there any way that I can only save state for that particular form?

Comment: I'm assuming then that you're using the same id for every wizard. The html attribute id should be unique and only used once per document. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: I have applied 'wizard-section' class for every wizard. But I don't understand what it has to do with the cookie? I mean wizards id/class will be same for different forms assigned to a user. It will use that cookie "jQu3ry_5teps_St%40te_wizard" for every forms and that is causing the problem.

Comment: The cookie key is concated from a hard-coded key, `jQu3ry_5teps_St@te_`, and `wizard.data( "uid " )`. The last part is either the id-attribute of the wizard element or an automatically incremented number. https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/blob/master/src/privates.js#L321 Meaning that if you use the same id-attribute for all the wizards they will end up with the same cookie-id.